# Configurable product is displayed in Magento Wishlist instead of the selected simple product

Tags: php, magento-1.9.1, configurable-product

I have created configurable products that have two associated simple products. When I select one of these, and add it to the shopping cart the correct image is displayed along with the correct price and format details.

However if I do the same thing and add the item to my Wishlist. The correct price and product details are displayed, however the configurable products image is displayed instead of the simple product that was selected.

This is the code I have done so far; however now I don't have any image being displayed in my Wishlist. The file I am modifying is app/design/frontend/customtheme/default/template/wishlist/item/column/image.phtml

```
<?php
$item = $this->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
$item_s = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->loadWithOptions($item->getId(), 'simple_product')->getOptionsByCode();
$simple_product = $item_s['simple_product']->getData();
$simple_product_id = $simple_product_data['product_id'];
$simple_product_attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple_product_id);
?>
<a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>">
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($simple_product_attr ,'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>" />
</a>
```

Also here is the code with extraneous code removed:

```
$item = $this->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
$item_s = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')
     ->loadWithOptions($item->getId(), 'simple_product')
     ->getOptionsByCode();
$simple_product = $item_s['simple_product']->getData();
$simple_product_id = $simple_product_data['product_id'];
$simple_product_attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($simple_product_id);
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($simple_product_attr ,'small_image'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

OK: I see a bug on your code ->

```
  **$simple_product** = $item_s['simple_product']->getData();
    $simple_product_id = **$simple_product_data**['product_id'];
```

change to

```
    $simple_product = $item_s['simple_product']->getData();
    $simple_product_id = $simple_product['product_id'];
```

After changing that you will be able to get your Simple Product.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but let me give the solution we've implemented and that finally worked for us.

Basic problem is the the media gallery needs to get initialized prior loading the images in this case.

So the code to get images loaded looks like this:

```
/* @var Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item $item */
$item = $this->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();

if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
    // Initialize media gallery
    $mediaBackend = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_backend_media');
    $mediaGalleryAttribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId(), 'media_gallery');
    $mediaBackend->setAttribute($mediaGalleryAttribute);

    // Get simple product
    $item_s = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')
        ->loadWithOptions($item->getId(), 'simple_product')
        ->getOptionsByCode();
    $simple_product = $item_s['simple_product']->getData();
    $simple_product_id = $simple_product['product_id'];

    // Load the product
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple_product_id);

    // Finally load the images
    $mediaBackend->afterLoad($product);
}
```

When this is done, you can call and display the image as it is already done in the template:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(750,900);
```

This is just a prototype we've done in the image.phtml template of the wishlist. Better solution would be to implement that code in the Model class, in the case of wishlist perhaps overriding `Wishlist/Model/Item.php`.

But watch out, afaik there need to be a few more things executed/checked in above code, especially when the product is initially added to the list. Pulling the single product via the list item ID may throw an error as the conf. product itself is inserted in the list.